# Laravel storage link doesn't point to the disk path (point to the default path)

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel 8 and Mediable library to manage my media. In public_html (main domain) everything is right, but a copy of website in subdomain goes wrong on saving media in storage path.
My filesystems.php:

```
'disks' => [
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
    ],
```

I'm trying to save my media like this:

```
$picture = MediaUploader::fromSource($request->file('picture'))
                ->toDestination('public', 'gallery')
                ->onDuplicateIncrement()
                ->useHashForFilename()
                ->upload();
                
$gallery->attachMedia($picture, ['gallery']);
```

but after saving the picture, the url of image that is `{Domain}/storage/gallery/{image}` should point to the `storage/app/public/gallery` but it point to the default location which is `public/storage/gallery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer was a symlink to the storage directory that I needed, use this code in index.php :

```
$app->bind('path.public', function () {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

and then use `php artisan storage:link` to make a symlink to the storage directory

Note: if you use a shared hosting and don't have access to shell, use Artisan facade like this in your web.php:

```
Route::get('link', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('storage:link');
    dd(Artisan::output());
});
```

and then call the `{Domain}/link` url to run the artisan command